# Serve most of a domain with Apache, but use mod_proxy to serve some URLs from Lighttpd

Tags: apache, apache2, iframe, lighttpd

So we wish to host some pages on a new server with apache2, and embed some of our old content & functionality from another server with lighttpd in an iframe. I'm looking at this configuration from the apache docs (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html#page-header)  under "Using Virtual_host and mod_proxy" together.

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.111.2/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.111.2/
   ServerName hostname.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

The only issue is that I want to proxy only on a subdomain, or even better, if I can keep the top domain and proxy only if the url contains a particular path ie. "/myprocess.php". So in essence the DNS will point to the apache2 as the "master router".

Answer (score 1):

You're probably best doing this using a setup of 3 *VirtualHost* declarations.

The first, becomes a default catch-all for any name that has not been specified, and you could have an index.php in the */var/www/default/* that either returns a blank page or an HTTP 404 response etc:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
  ServerName hostname.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/default
  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/default/error_log
  TransferLog /var/log/httpd/default/access_log
</VirtualHost>
```

The second, becomes your main new website using the domain `www.example.com`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
  ServerName www.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/default
  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/newsite/error_log
  TransferLog /var/log/httpd/newsite/access_log
</VirtualHost>
```

The third, works as a proxy to your old website using the subdomain `oldsite.example.com`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
  ServerName oldsite.example.com
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://192.168.111.2/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.111.2/
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/oldsite/error_log
  TransferLog /var/log/httpd/oldsite/access_log
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod_rewrite to set rules about which URLs should be served via reverse proxy.  There is documentation about it on the Apache website: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/proxy.html